# Tilemap for square component in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I'm extremely new to coding in Unity and I'm having issues figuring out how to implement a feature using a tilemap for a 2D Game. The goal is to have a user be able to open a menu where they can draw pixel art on a given part of the screen, close the menu, and place the new painting on a wall.

I've experimented with a few options, and the typical nomenclature seems to be using a tilemap and connecting a user's click on the screen to the specific tile, then setting the color based on the color selected. My thought was to create a square GameObject, and then apply a TileMap to it. However, all of my searches yield using a tilemap for the *entire* screen/backgrounds, not necessarily a menu. My searches with the "TileMap" component have also been fruitless, and I'm struggling to figure out how to add a TileMap to only part of a screen (or if that's even possible).

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: using tilemap seems a bit overkill to me .. sounds like you rather simply want some paint to texture feature ...

Comment: @derHugo where would I go to research that feature? like I said, any advice appreciated!

Comment: You could start with a [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+runtime+paint+on+texture) and then dig into the subject .. StackOverflow is not about providing you links and tutorials but rather for asking about a specific issue regarding a specific implementation detail

Comment: @derHugo I understand, but part of the issue is learning WHAT to google. I appreciate your help with the search, because without it I would have probably spent a few days trying to find what I'm looking for (which I already have, resulting in this stackoverflow post). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I won't advise using tilemap that way because it will get complicated very fast unless you are really familiar with the Unity tilemap. But if you insist, there are methods in the [tilemap](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.html) call [SetTile](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.SetTile.html) and [GetTile](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.GetTile.html).

Alternatively, I would advise you to make your own custum grid system so it only have the functions that you need. Then, save the grid colored data into a 2Dtexture. Then, set this texture to a material, and make a 3d game object quad to use this material.

If you still have no clue where to start, here's a tutorial on how to create pixel art on a custom grid similar to what you mentioned : [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rfoyh3GOhOE&ab_channel=CodeMonkey)